# Is histogram enough for image classification using Neural Networks?

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing, neural-network

I am trying to make a simple application in order to classify images using a Self-Organizing Map. I am using Java 8 and OpenCV 320. I used 20 images with flowers and 20 images with dogs. So the result that I want is 2 clusters: one containing flowers, the other one the dogs.

What I did:

```
1) I resized the images to 500 x 500.
2) I converted the RGB images to Grayscale
3) I applied Imgproc.equalizeHist(grayscaleImage, histogram) for each image;
4) I applied Imgproc.calcHist(image,new MatOfInt(0),new Mat(),histogram,new MatOfInt(256),ranges) for each image (ranges = new MatOfFloat(0f, 256f); )
5) I applied Core.normalize(histogram, histogram, 0, histogram.rows(), Core.NORM_MINMAX);
6) I also wanted to reduce the histogram by applying PCACompute with max of 125 components but I received a 1 x 1 eigenvectors when I was expecting 125 x 1. I don't know why this happened but I got rid of this. Maybe someone can explain it to me.
7) I fed the numbers obtained from the histogram to the SOM.
```

The problem that I have is that my SOM doesn't classify the flowers and dogs correctly. It's like each image is in it's own cluster. Is the histogram data not enough for such a classification or am I doing something wrong? Thank you to everyone.

Comment: Well, if you want to use histograms, you'd better use _color_ histograms, i.e. compute that on color images. However, for any non-trivial problem they are not very useful.

Comment: @Miki Thanks for the information. Color histograms would have 3 planes for R, G and B. Is there a method to turn this into only 1 plane? Like a single array? Or what else can I do besides histograms in order to classify images with my Self-Organizing Map?

Comment: You can have either a 3D array, or a regular 2D array where you concatenate the histogram computed separately for the 3 channels. I don't know SOM.. but you can start looking at [Bag of Words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bag-of-words_model_in_computer_vision) approach... it's a little outdated, but it's farily simple and works usually quite well